# Retrieving the linear expression value

Tags: python, or-tools

I would like to know how can I retrieve the linear expression value to show in my result. In my problem, I have the following expression:

```
total_cost = solver.Sum(supplier_cost[j] for j in range(num_suppliers))
```

And I'm trying to show the value of the expression this way:

```
print('Total cost = ', total_cost)
```

But, instead, what is shown in **print('Total cost = ', total_cost)** is: (I did not put the entire value because the text was too long)

```
Total cost =  ((((0.0 * <ortools.linear_solver.linear_solver_natural_api.VariableExpr object at 0x7fe188875898>) + (0.0 * <ortools.linear_solver.linear_solver_natural_api.VariableExpr object at 0x7fe188875048>) + (0.0 * <ortools.linear_solver.linear_solver_natural_api.VariableExpr object at 0x7fe188875ac8>) + (0.0 * <ortools.linear_solver.linear_solver_natural_...
```

Comment: Try `total_cost.solution_value()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Stradivari answered, to retrieve the expression value, we need to call the method solution_value().

```
total_cost.solution_value()
```